# How to load a http .txt file as a Java FileSystem

Tags: java, file, nio, nio2

I am studying for the Java 1.8 OCP exam and I ran across something in the Oracle study guide p.459 where it says you can load a remote URL as a FileSystem object.  I tried this and can't get it to work.   What is the simplest hello-world style answer to get this working?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
public class FileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
        FileSystem remoteFS = FileSystems.getFileSystem(
            new URI("http://www.gutenberg.org/files/55007")
        );
        Path remotePath = remoteFS.getPath("55007-0.txt");
        System.out.println(remotePath.isAbsolute());
    }
}
```

It throws the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: 
  Provider "http" not found
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getFileSystem(FileSystems.java:224)
    at qa.test.FileTest.main(FileTest.java:7)
```

---

Addendum:
FileSystemProvider.installedProviders() returns

[sun.nio.fs.MacOSXFileSystemProvider@4554617c, com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider@74a14482]

Comment: " where it says you can load a remote URL as a FileSystem object." Are you sure ? The method takes as parameter an URI and not an URL. It doesn't make no sense to provide an URL as an URL is not necessary compatible with all FileSystems.

Comment: @davidxx  Yes, the JavaDoc says it takes a URI.  I followed a whole rabbit trail down Google searches and couldn't figure it out.  Seems like 'http provider'  would/should be built-in but it appears I need to do something special,  like write a custom handler that converts the URI to a URL  (among other things)?

Comment: `FileSystemProvider.installedProviders()` returns a list of installed providers.

Comment: What is the exact wording?

Comment: what if you use `file://` or `ftp://` over http?